# Can Workflow be used to restrict the publishing/editing of a Page and its Components on selected Publications?

Tags: event-system, web8.5, workflow

I have a requirement where we want to restrict the editing or publishing of a Page and its Components for certain Publications. 
However, we  don't want this restriction to be applied to all Publications and the User can still approve the Pages for some other Publications as per their business requirement.

Can this be achieved using Workflows where a User can simply approve the Pages for specific Publications and can choose to do it later for the other Publications too?

However, we don't want to put Workflow in each Publication by localizing the Schemas, rather the idea is that on the Master Publication (inherited by all other Country Publications) the set of Content Editors once done with the creation of Pages can submit the Pages to Workflow & Approver can get the list of all Child Publications (in a form of Checkbox or Dropdown) where he can select the Publications where the Pages can be edited/published & later if he wants to add more Publications in the approved list he can make the change.

Comment: Any progress in the issue you have?plz share it with others

Answer (score 6):

If your difference is based on the user's role in certain Publications, I would first consider adjusting authorization in terms of rights, groups, and maybe permissions.

Otherwise yes, you could have Publication-specific Workflow Processes by unchecking the Publication setting for sharing workflows. See my post on [Bundle Workflow for SDL Tridion 2013](https://community.sdl.com/product-groups/sdl-tridion-dx/tridion-sites/tridion-developer/b/weblog/posts/setting-up-sdl-tridion-multi-item-workflow-with-bundles) (most of the details still apply) for this setting:

[image: Enable or disable workflow sharing in Publication settings]

You could then localize Schemas to set different workflows per item across the BluePrint.

Alternatively, you could consider including Publication-specific logic in your Workflow Process Definition, but that seems harder to maintain to me.

*I'm sure there are other solutions depending on your requirements. I'd just recommend confirming how the workflow process differs by group, content, and Publication to balance maintainability and flexibility.*

**Update**: for scenarios where content creators should be able to influence the process of items in other publications, maybe consider Bundle (and/or item) Metadata to let the content creator adjust how the items are reviewed. This could influence a single workflow process or maybe start new ones, maybe?

Alternatively, you could have different workflow processes to let a certain process complete before starting the editing and publishing process.

I'm not sure, though, on making the list of Publications that allow editing and publishing changeable at any time. I'll let others answer; it could help if you add more details on how or when content creators would change these settings.

Comment: Thanks, @alvin, but you are right we don't want to add extra maintenance activities by enabling the WF on each publication, I have updated my question with what we want to achieve, not sure though if that's is possible.

Comment: Okay, I updated my answer to suggest bundle metadata as an option, but it depends on your use case. You have the flexibility to have different workflow options where editors can choose what process to follow as well as programmatic ways to interact with the items while in workflow, but the workflow processes are mostly independent of each other.